# count number of cycles with length n in a directed graph

Tags: python, algorithm

I have searched for a while and found multiple algorithms to [detect](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-in-a-graph/) cycle in directed graphs, but I am interested to determine the length of cycle.

on the other hand there is also algorithm that works only for undirected graphs [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cycles-of-length-n-in-an-undirected-and-connected-graph/).

```py
def DFS(V, graph, marked, n, vert, start, count):
    """
    Python Program to count cycles of length n in a given graph.
    """

    # mark the vertex vert as visited
    marked[vert] = True

    # if the path of length (n-1) is found
    if n == 0:

        # mark vert as un-visited to make it usable again.
        marked[vert] = False

        # Check if vertex vert can end with vertex start
        if graph[vert][start] == 1:
            count = count + 1
            return count
        else:
            return count

    # For searching every possible path of length (n-1)
    for i in range(V):
        if marked[i] == False and graph[vert][i] == 1:

            # DFS for searching path by decreasing length by 1
            count = DFS(V, graph, marked, n-1, i, start, count)

    # marking vert as unvisited to make it usable again.
    marked[vert] = False
    return count


def countCycles(graph, n, V):
    '''Counts cycles of length N in an undirected
    and connected graph.
    '''

    # all vertex are marked un-visited initially.
    marked = [False] * V

    # Searching for cycle by using v-n+1 vertices
    count = 0
    for i in range(V-(n-1)):
        count = DFS(V, graph, marked, n-1, i, i, count)

        # ith vertex is marked as visited and
        # will not be visited again.
        marked[i] = True

    return int(count/2)

V = 5 # number of vertex
adj0 = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                 [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]])

for i in [3, 4]:
    print(f"number of cycle with length {i} is" , helpers.countCycles(adj0.tolist(), i, V))

# number of cycle with length 3 is 3
# number of cycle with length 4 is 2
```

How to combine these to have an algorithm to look for a cycle with determined length?

[image]

Comment: The image depicts an undirected graph. Not sure how it relates to your question. Also, the code you have presented defines an adjacency matrix, which can be interpreted as a directed graph, that happens to have an edge from b to a when there is one from a to b. Just define your directed graph in that matrix, and it should work. If not, please provide input and expected output and how it differs from the actual output.

Comment: Yes, seems it works, just need to remove the devision by 2.

Comment: looking for a cycle is very different from counting the number of cycles.  Which do you want?

Comment: @MattTimmermans I want to count the number of cycles with length 3,4,5,.. on a directed network.

Answer (score 2):

Start with an adjacency matrix **M** such that there is a 1 at row j, column i if there is an arc from vertex i to vertex j, and 0 otherwise.  Note the ordering -- each vertex's arcs are represented by a *column* in this matrix, so it's the transpose of the more common row-major order for adjacency matrices.

Now, If we define a vertex vector **V<sub>i</sub>** to be a column vector that has a 1 in row i and 0 everywhere else, then the product **MV<sub>i</sub>** gives the number of ways that you can get from vertex i to every other vertex in **one step**.  The sum of the diagonal elements is the **number of length-1 cycles**.

Using matrix [exponentiation-by-squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), you can calculate **M<sup>n</sup>** in O(|V|<sup>3</sup> log n) time†.  For every vertex vector, then **M<sup>n</sup>V<sub>i</sub>** gives the number of ways you can get from vertex i to every other vertex in **n steps**, and the sum of the diagonal elements of **M<sup>n</sup>** is the **total number of length-n cycles**.

† - caveat: the O(|V|<sup>3</sup> log n) time assumes constant times for mathematical operations, which is not necessarily true, since the numbers involved can get very large.

Comment: Is it the same method represented in "Clustering in complex directed networks", Fagiolo PRE2007, table1? I could not found a relation between this method and counting the number of cycles from DFS algorithm. I need to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Performance note.  Set `n` to be the size of the graph, and you have the [Hamiltonian Cycle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem).  This is well-known to be NP-complete.  Conversely this means that, even if you were told the `n` points that contain the cycle, verifying that there is a cycle of length `n` in those points is still hard.

Therefore while producing a correct algorithm isn't that hard, producing an efficient one is a different story.

Comment: The question doesn't require *simple* cycles.